# Remove signatures from URLs in AWS Carrierwave to speed up loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm uploading lots of images to S3 with Carrierwave,
but my URLS contain aws signatures which leads to very slow loading times.

**When retrieving a JSON with 200 records, each image url looks like this:**

```
"url":"https://.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/uploads/product/images/1156/1.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\u0026X-Amz-Credential=XXX%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request\u0026X-Amz-Date=20220921T151258Z\u0026X-Amz-Expires=604800\u0026X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\u0026X-Amz-Signature=XXXX
```

**¿How can I sign all of the bucket globally or remove the signature from each url?**

I've tried `config.fog_public = false`, `config.aws_acl    = :authenticated_read` with no luck.

**Carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] # for AWS-side bucket access permissions config, see section below
  config.aws_acl    = :authenticated_read
  config.fog_public = false

  # Optionally define an asset host for configurations that are fronted by a
  # content host, such as CloudFront.

  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

  # Set custom options such as cache control to leverage browser caching.
  # You can use either a static Hash or a Proc.
  config.aws_attributes = -> { {
    expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
    cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
  } }

  config.aws_credentials = {
    access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region:            ENV['AWS_REGION'], # Required
    stub_responses:    Rails.env.test? # Optional, avoid hitting S3 actual during tests
  }

  # Optional: Signing of download urls, e.g. for serving private content through
  # CloudFront. Be sure you have the `cloudfront-signer` gem installed and
  # configured:
  # config.aws_signer = -> (unsigned_url, options) do
  #   Aws::CF::Signer.sign_url(unsigned_url, options)
  # end
end
```

Comment: Uploading?  If you have an S3 url doesn't that mean the images are already in s3?

Comment: @dbugger the problem comes when I retrieve them from their URLS to show them (uploading works fine)

Comment: Any reason you are getting the urls before they are needed -- I'd just show a link to the file and have the controller action build the url when a user wants to download the file.

Comment: I'm using Vue.js so I need to retrieve all of the URLS from a JSON file (generated in Rails controller)

Comment: You can do the same thing on vue.  Just have vue retrieve each url on an as needed basis instead of binding them all to the model.